# Interfaces problems with java

Tags: java, interface, casting, jaxb

i have a problem with utilization of interfaces in java. I'll show you the code it will be more explicit :

I use jaxb to extract datas from an XML config file :

```
public class LoadFilePollerConfiguration implements IConfig{

    File configFile = new File("config.xml");

    @Override
    public void loadConfiguration() throws Exception  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        loadFilePollerConfiguration();
    }

    private void loadFilePollerConfiguration() throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance
                (XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("config.xsd"));
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(FilePollerConfiguration.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());
        FilePollerConfiguration f = (FilePollerConfiguration)
                unmarshaller.unmarshal(configFile);

        Marshaller mar = jc.createMarshaller();
        mar.marshal(f, new File("test.xml"));

    }

}
```

I'll show you the IConfig interface :

```
public interface IConfig {

    public void loadConfiguration() throws Exception;

}
```

I have a class used to poll repositories and i'm using this function in my main, what is making me some troubles :

```
public class WatchSer {    

    private final WatchService watcher;     
    private final Map<WatchKey,Path> keys;          
    private boolean trace = false;  
    private FilePollerConfiguration configuration;

    WatchSer(IConfig conf) throws IOException {    

        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();         
        this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();   
        configuration = (FilePollerConfiguration) conf;

    }

    public ArrayList<IConfig> getAction(File file, String Event) {

        Pattern p;

        for(int i = 0; i < configuration.directoriesList.size(); i++){
            p =  Pattern.compile(configuration
                              .directoriesList.get(i).toString());
            System.out.println(p);

        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

And finally the main who instantiate loadFilePollerConfiguration class, use the loadConfiguration(). Until here, it'ok but when i want to create a WatchSer, i have a cast problem :

>

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LoadFilePollerConfiguration l = new LoadFilePollerConfiguration();
        l.loadConfiguration();
        WatchSer w = new WatchSer(l);
        w.getAction(new File("C://Users//jmoreau040612
                    //Desktop//New//yop.xml"),  "create");
    }
```

}

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: LoadFilePollerConfiguration cannot be cast to FilePollerConfiguration**

Comment: You should not have a method `loadFilePollerConfiguration()`, it looks like a constructor.

Comment: @julien: can you post your complete stack trace

Answer (score 1):

`LoadFilePollerConfiguration` can be cast into `FilePollerConfiguration` only if `LoadFilePollerConfiguration` extends `FilePollerConfiguration`.

From your question it seems you have misunderstood the concept of Interface. To explain further look at the following code.

```
Inteface iSample {
  void doThing();
  //more code
}

class Parent implements iSample {
  void doThing() {
     System.out.println("Parent");
  }
}

class AnotherParent implements iSample {
  void doThing() {
     System.out.println("Another Parent");
  }
}

class Child extends Parent implements iSample{
   //child specific code
}

class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       iSample i = new Parent();
       iSample j = new AnotherParent();
       iSample k = new Child();
       Parent p = j; //error
   }
}
```

just because `Parent` and `AnotherParent` implements `iSample` it doesn't mean a `Parent` object can hold a object of `AnotherParent`. But a reference of interface `iSample` can hold `Parent` and `AnotherParent` as both implements `iSample` and it can hold an instance of `Child` too as its **superclass has completed the interface contract**.

Comment: i believe he has not disclosed his entire stack trace. if the error is not thrown from the constructor of `Watchser` can you tell me where this error is thrown from?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example @Black Panther ! The problem was not that. I just had to remove my loadFilePollerConfiguration class which was useless.

Comment: @JulienMoreau: please post you own answer and accept it so that others can know the solutions. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem exits in the WatchSer constructor

```
public class WatchSer {    

    private final WatchService watcher;     
    private final Map<WatchKey,Path> keys;          
    private boolean trace = false;  
    private FilePollerConfiguration configuration;

    WatchSer(IConfig conf) throws IOException {    

        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();         
        this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();   
        configuration = (**FilePollerConfiguration**) conf;

    }
```

where 'FilePollerConfiguration' should be 'LoadFilePollerConfiguration'

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i was not that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i deleted my loadFilePollerConfiguration class and i modified my main like that :

```
public class Main {

    private IConfig loadConfig(File configFile) throws Exception{
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance
                      (XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("config.xsd"));
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance
                      (FilePollerConfiguration.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());
        FilePollerConfiguration f = (FilePollerConfiguration)  unmarshaller
                      .unmarshal(configFile);

        Marshaller mar = jc.createMarshaller();
        mar.marshal(f, new File("test.xml"));

        return f;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        IConfig conf = new Main().loadConfig(
                       new File("P://Projects//FileTransfer//config.xml"));
        WatchSer w = new WatchSer(conf);
        w.getAction(new File("C://Users//jmoreau040612//
                       Desktop//Old"), "create");
        //w.processEvents();
    }
```

}